# Does Yodlee capture transaction data in real-time or is there some lag?

Tags: yodlee

Does Yodlee's transaction data for a user update in real time or is there a lag as they pull the data from my source bank? As an example - Let's say I am a user and a credit card transaction posts today, 5/12. If I call the Yodlee API a couple hours after the transaction posts, will Yodlee return this transaction? If not, what roughly is the delay?

Thanks you very much for the help!
John

Comment: Hi John, yes I am facing the same problem with Yodlee. There is some lag from Yodlee site and this lag changes according to sites. Not fixed delay time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Yodlee transactions pull is not real time. As this will crash the bank servers, as if Yodlee will try to poll/login at the bank sites multiple times a day.

Yodlee do refresh accounts once in a day, you can find the time when it is going to be refreshed/updated with latest information using nextScheduledRefresh field. This also depends upon how active user is, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Platform_Overview/Refresh_Policy).